# Which is the better of coding to get optimal performance in spark

Tags: python, pyspark

If i need to do a transformation on a dataframe(for example adding a column) , which is the better way to get optimal performance?.

1.

```
a=[1,2,3]
df=spark.createDataframe(a)
df=df.withColumn("b",lit(1))
```

2.

```
a=[1,2,3]
df=spark.createDataframe(a)
df2=df.withColumn("b",lit(1))
```

Consider i am adding 200 columns.

Comment: are you trying to ask new df vs old df? which one is good performance wise?

Comment: Yes I m trying to understand which one is better way of coding creating new dataframe for each column o altering same dataframe...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
withColumn
```

will be evaluated lazily, so you need to understand how you are going add new column to same data frame  without calling an action statement.

As far as your question you can use same data frame if every time you are going to use the latest(updated) data frame, considering you don't need the `df` further.

Hope it's clear

Answer (score 0):

When you use withcolumn to add a new column in spark df, a new narrow task is added to the execution plan for each withcolumn statement. You can try the method specified in this [blog](https://lansalo.com/2018/05/13/spark-how-to-add-multiple-columns-in-dataframes-and-how-not-to/). This explains the scenario properly.

Comment: This helps..but also I would like to understand if creating mutilple dataframes (as specified in code 2 ) is a better way or if adding column to same dataframe a better way(as specified in code 1)...?

Comment: It doesn't create multiple dataframes. It modifies the dataframe on a row level so it just happens in a single iteration where as in withcolumn, multiple narrow steps needs to be executed and thus a huge execution plan will be created in the driver.

Comment: To answer your question, which way is better, I don't think it should matter from execution point of view as they will be evaluated lazily. It wouldn't make any difference to the execution plan. You can try this small case and check the execution plan. It will be helpful.